# Optimal meeting location based on rank

Tags: python, algorithm

This sounds like a very common problem. Perhaps there's even a website that can solve it for me? If not, I'm sure there must be some python library and few lines of code that would help.

Let's say I have 10 people and 5 possible locations for a meeting. How would I find the optimal meeting location? I know people's preferences, e.g., Person 1 would rank the locations going from best to worst as: Location D, Location A, Location C; Person 2 - Location B, Location A, Location D, Location C; and so on. Note that rankings might not include all 5 locations, in other words - how would I deal with missing rankings?

How would I code this in Python to find the best solution? Or perhaps there's an online service that I can use to figure this out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are only ranked and not weighted, this is an example of a [Condorcet vote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_method). Pseudocode for the Schulze method looks to be [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schulze_method#Implementation).

ADDITION

Just do a search on Google for "Python Condorcet" - many results appear with free code.

ADDITION 2

First listed project names on github:

[bradbeattie/python-vote-core](https://github.com/bradbeattie/python-vote-core)

[radii/condorcet](https://github.com/radii/condorcet)

And a StackExchange Code Review:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42359/condorcet-voting-method-in-oop-python

The relevant quotation from the forementioned  Wikipedia link:

> The only difficult step in implementing the Schulze method is computing the strongest path strengths. However, this is a well-known problem in graph theory sometimes called the widest path problem. One simple way to compute the strengths therefore is a variant of the Floyd–Warshall algorithm. The following pseudocode illustrates the algorithm.

```
# Input: d[i,j], the number of voters who prefer candidate i to candidate j.
# Output: p[i,j], the strength of the strongest path from candidate i to candidate j.

for i from 1 to C
    for j from 1 to C
      if (i ≠ j) then
         if (d[i,j] > d[j,i]) then
            p[i,j] := d[i,j]
         else
            p[i,j] := 0

for i from 1 to C
   for j from 1 to C
      if (i ≠ j) then
         for k from 1 to C
            if (i ≠ k and j ≠ k) then
               p[j,k] := max ( p[j,k], min ( p[j,i], p[i,k] ) )
```

> This algorithm is efficient, and has running time proportional to C3 where C is the number of candidates. (This does not account for the running time of computing the d[*,*] values, which if implemented in the most straightforward way, takes time proportional to C2 times the number of voters.)